# Why is the seder "beseder" (in order)?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada

Is there any halachic reason why we do the seder in the order that we do? It seems that many of the components of the seder are halachically mandated, but is there any halachic mandate that we do them in a particular order, or is this just a custom that has arisen?

Comment: Well, the different *seder* parts have a nice rhyming: *Kadesh uRchatz - Karpas Yachatz, Magid Rachtza - Motzi Matza* etc.

Comment: Well, _kadesh_, _rochtza_, _motzi matza_, and _barech_ pretty obviously (I think) have to be in that order. Likewise _kadesh_, _shulchan orech_, and _barech_.

Comment: @yair That's probably _post facto_ to the decision to have it in roughly that order.

Comment: @msh210 yeah some of them are obvious. For example, urchatz must come before karpas, but that could really be anywhere in the seder, as well as korech.

Comment: Comment on my previous comment: Actually, _kadesh_ before _rochtza_ isn't obvious to all. (Some usually wash hands before _kidush_ rather than after.)

Comment: Almost all of the Seder is minhag (custom), from the saying of Halachot (אפילו כולנו חכמים, etc), to the songs at the end, to the opening of the door for Eliyahu, to the dipping of the fingers for the plagues...  What's unique about this aspect that makes it worth questioning?

Comment: @ShmuelL Well I would say the fact that we make such a big deal about the order of the Seder makes me wonder *why* we do it in that order at all. It *is* called the Seder after all.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include some detail of which steps seem out of order? The whole thing is pretty reasonable to me. What are you confused about? Kiddush Questions Story Eat Hallel. I wouldn't have had it any other way.

Comment: @DoubleAA why Yachatz after Karpas? Why tzafun at the end? Why hallel after barech? Etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the seder is discussed in Shulchah Aruch, see Simon tuf-ayin-beis  Dinei Haseva and Daled Kosus (472, laws reclining and the four cups),  tuf ayin-gimmel, dinei kos rishon v'seder hapesach until kos sheni (473, laws of the first cup and seder of pesach until the second up), and so forth until tuf-peh-aleph, sh'lo l'shtot achar arbeh kosos (481, not to drink after the four cups).

See Shulchan Harav (the same simonim), now available in English, for a concise presentation.  Note also, that in some instances, doing an item out of order, can create a halachic issue.

Here is a short explanation of the order:

Kadesh is necessarily the first thing, in any yom tov or shabbos meal.(Shulchan Aruch 472:1 and Magen Avraham, Sulchan Aruch Harav, 472:1)

Urechatz - we have to wash before handling wet food (without making the beracho netilas yadayim, see the discussion in Shulchan Aruch 473:6, T"z 7, Sh. HaRav 473:4).

Karpas - we awaken the child's curiosity before we start the story,

Yachtza - we tell the story over a poor man's bread, we need that the others remain whole to make the berachos later

Maggid - we are obligated to tell the story, fulfilling the passage when your child asks, and while the Matzoh is in front of us (See Mishnah Pesachim 10:4 regarding the questions and outline).

Rachtzah - now we are going to eat the matzo, we have to wash with a beracha

Motzi - we have to make a beracho hamotzi to eat the matzo

Matza - we make a beracho on the mitzvoh we are about to perform, eating the matzo, it is not an interruption after hamotzi, because it is required for the eating.

Maror - another obligation, matzo and maror

Koreh - we are still working on the requirement matzo and maror

Shulchan Aruch - now we can eat, and we need to eat a festive meal because it is yom tov

Tzafun -this is in place of the lamb, which is to be eaten on a full stomach

Beirach - benching after the meal

Hallel, Nirtzah - we started this in the haggada. The first part refered to the redemption from Egypt. Here we say the part that refers to the miracles that will happen in the future (Pesachim 118a, Zevach Pesach) and again, we sing praises over a cup of wine, and finally, pray that our service be accepted.

Comment: What about all the different steps you grouped into the title "maggid"?

Comment: Rambam writes that one does make a Bracha even at Urchatz.

Comment: You don’t explain why we have to do Maggid (and everything required for Maggid) before the meal. Maybe we should do Kiddush, Matzah and Marror, then Maggid, then Shulchan Orech?

Comment: @Don Most Rishonim thought you must wash on wet foods like most salads (and of course you say a blessing before the mitzva) Some thought you don't need to wash at all (and no blessing on a non Mitzva :)). There's a later compromise out there to wash without a blessing just in case. Additionally, there's a dispute if one must wash at all before eating less than an eggs worth of bread with a similar outcome. Thus one doesn't say a blessing on "Rachtza" unless they plan on eating a lot of Matza right away (most don't). This is all true in general. The Seder is just an application of regular laws.

Comment: @DonielF  I appreciate your comment and I will think about it.  But, keep in mind, this is a high level list while the shulchan aruch gives it 10 siminon.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why it must be in this particular order. For example, maggid and matzah are both obligations that we don't delay until after eating. But why not do matzah before maggid?

Comment: @Daniel  Do you eat before you daven maariv?  Why not?   See the last two lines in Double AA's comment.   Not nice to down vote before discussing it.

Comment: @DrM I didn't downvote (although commenting is not required before downvoting). I'm not sure what eating before davening maariv has to do with anything

Comment: There is no obligation to ask four questions. In fact some manuscripts of the Mishna only had 3 and the Talmud allows just saying 1.

Comment: @DrM I’m the one who downvoted, on the grounds of my earlier comment. You explain why we do things relative to what comes after them, not relative to what comes before them. It’s fine that we have to wash before Matzah, and that Matzah has to come first in the meal, but you never explain why the meal has to come after Maggid. Likewise, you never explain why Hallel comes last.

Comment: @DonielF  There are two reasons,  You cant eat while you have that kind of obligation, and you have to tell the story while the matzoh is in front of you.  I wil think about this and see how to work it in.  My first reaction to the down vote was to delete the whole thing. I get enough shailos to answer in the real world without having to contribute to the site and be denigrated.

Comment: @Double AA, I don't think that I said there is an obligation specifically.  I only provided the cite to the Mishna where the subjet is taken up.  Nonetheless, per your comment, I edited that part to make it less ambiguos.   Now that there are two down votes, I am seriously considering deleting it.  I am happy to sharpen this up in response to comments. I am not willing to be treated rudely for the effort.

Comment: @DrM 1. I don’t see that in your answer at all. 2. Where do you get your first reason from? 3. Chas v’shalom that I’m denigrating *you*. A downvote means that I find the answer “unhelpful,” as per the tooltip. Most of the post is still answering why we do these things, not why we do them when we do them.

Comment: @DonielF, it really does explain the order, for most part all according to halachah.   Ther are a few details that I have been adding as people raise questions.  That is helpful.  I just added a little more on maggid.

Comment: Your answer is definitely much better than it was before. I've swapped my downvote for an upvote.